# Text webpart - edit hyperlink on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, content-editor-web-part, text-webpart

When I select the text that has the hyperlink, then click edit and the box with the link is empty ("https: //") even though the link is clickable and takes you to the correct page.

In addition, when I enter a new link in this empty field and publish the page, the text loses formatting and the hyperlink is removed.

[image: hyperlink editor]

I have reported this issue to MS, but they do nothing except collecting logs for a month.

Comment: The production engineer found the problem and released an update that patches this error. When the patch will be uploaded to my Tenant I will close the post, if not we will continue to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue in my SharePoint Online site.

How did you add the hyperlink in the Text web part?

If the issue exists when you add a custom internet web site such as "https://www.google.com" instead of SharePoint page?

Create a new page and insert the hyperlink and check if the issue exists.

Comment: the problem depends on the content we enter in webpart "text". due to the secrets of the text, I cannot place it here. This is plain text with hyperlinks and with formatting of color and font size / thickness